# UnknownCodecException kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to read from a topic from Kafka (in Java) but this exception is always launching:

```
 kafka.common.UnknownCodecException: 3 is an unknown compression codec
    at kafka.message.CompressionCodec$.getCompressionCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:26)
    at kafka.message.Message.compressionCodec(Message.scala:213)
    at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$$anon$1.makeNextOuter(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:173)
    at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$$anon$1.makeNext(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:191)
    at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$$anon$1.makeNext(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:145)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.hasNext(Iterator.scala:847)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.skip(Iterator.scala:612)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:615)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.insertAll(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:99)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

For the consumer the properties are:

```
group.id=groupTest123
consumer.id=consumerid
client.id=clientid
auto.offset.reset=smallest
```

and for the producer:

```
acks=1
buffer.memory=67108864
compression.type=none
batch.size=16384
linger.ms=0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: you are using a wrong codec. Could you post your configuration (for the producer/consumer)?

Comment: Please update your question with the properties (for the producer and consumer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression type `3` stands for `LZ4` compression which is obviously not supported by the client you use. See [compression types](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/record/CompressionType.java#L23) for reference. If I remember correctly, LZ4 was added in `0.8.2` or something.

I'm not sure if there's any spark integration able to handle LZ4 compressed Kafka payloads, so I think you could try using GZIP or Snappy compression on the producer side, if that's possible.